# State Identification (States of significance)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

**Here is a short identification puzzle inspired by a road trip across the U.S.**

*There are four sets of clues, each identifying a state.

Please identify each state and what they have in common/why they specifically are significant.

A clue or set of clues may have multiple possible answers, but only one combination forms a complete answer.*

a)

- Not one of the original states
- [image] is on its right
- [image] could fit within it
- The last letter is the same as the first letter
- [image: mystery flag]
- Imports false charity into the Keystone State

b)

- Near [image]
- Nearly [image]
- Associated with cars and also pollution
- Quite low density

c)

- Potatoes, say
- Imports crude petroleum into the Mount Rushmore State
- Has a recognizable shape
- Contains part of the mind (Freudian)

d)

- [image: 10,000 lakes, generally]
- Has more freedom than (c)
- Forms part of Lake Superior
- [image: images]
- Also contains a part of the mind

Hint:

> Little or no knowledge is required to solve this puzzle. There are a few viable break-in points (in my opinion); solving any will quickly lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These four states are...

> the four states of matter! ***From OP:** matter is a synonym for "significance", as per the title*

The first state is...

> Plasma

Explanation:

> Plasma isn't one of the "original" states of matter (solid, liquid, and gas). Massachusetts is on its right (plas**MA**), and Louisiana could fit within it (p**LA**sma). The last letter (in "plasm**a**") is the same as the first (in the alphabet). Hidden from Arizona's flag is a star, and stars are made of plasma. "Imports false charity into the Keystone State" is almost a cryptic clue, where "charity" = "alms": `P(LASM)*A`.

The second state is...

> Gas

Explanation:

> Montana's abbreviation is "MT", and <s>fuel gauges have "empty" on them</s> ***from OP:** gas is mostly "empty" space*. "**GA**s" is nearly Georgia (GA). Gas is used to fuel cars, pollution is commonly gaseous, and gas is quite low density.

The third state is...

> Solid

Explanation:

> Potatoes are an example of a solid. "Imports crude petroleum into the Mount Rushmore State" is another almost-cryptic-clue, where "petroleum" = "oil": `S(OLI)*D`. Solids can hold their shape (and thus have recognizable shapes) and contain part of the mind, according to Freud: sol**ID**.

The fourth state is...

> Liquid

Explanation:

> Lakes are generally liquid, and can change their shape more easily than solids. <s>You can have *liquid* assets and *river* banks, but deserts and brick houses are usually dry?</s> ***From OP:** "Stocks and cash/cash accounts are considered liquid assets; land and buildings are not."* Liquids also contain part of the mind, according to Freud: liqu**ID**.

Comment: Oh, well done :) Now that I read your answer I understand that I had made a massive assumption throughout, which the OP has been very careful never to *state*... I'd even solved some of the more cryptic clues and rejected the answers because they didn't fit my preconception. Great work seeing through the deception!

Comment: @Stiv Why thank you! :D When I first saw the puzzle, I thought that there would be something tricky afoot; it just took me coming back to it later for the pieces to click

Comment: Great work! Some notes on intention: (rot13: Tnf vgfrys vf zbfgyl rzcgl. Fgbpxf naq pnfu/pnfu nppbhagf ner pbafvqrerq yvdhvq nffrgf; ynaq naq ohvyqvatf ner abg. Nyfb gur gvgyr 'Fgngrf bs Fvtavsvpnapr' vf n flabalz sbe lbhe nafjre)

Comment: @Amoz Thanks for the clarification; I added it to my answer (I was almost on the right track for the rot13(yvdhvq nffrgf) part! XD) Great misdirection throughout, and it was a fun solve once I figured out what was happening!